# BPEL for data synchronization

Tags: oracle, synchronization, bpel

I am trying to use Oracle SOA BPEL to synch data of about 1000 employees between an HR service and our local db.  I get IDs of all employees with a findEmp call and loop through it empCount times to getEmp(empID) from the same HR service and update/insert into our db in every loop.  This times out after about 60 odd employees, though this process is an asynch process.  How should I redesign the process flow?

Comment: I created a process that calls findEmp and another that synch a single emp using getEmp(id).  I invoked one-way calls to the latter in a loop, no more timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout is occuring because you don't have any dehydration points in your BPEL code. Oracle BPEL needs to dehydrate before the Java transaction times out.
If you are using the Oracle BPEL DB Adapter, you can actually submit many objects at once for processing to the database, simply put more than one in the  element from the DB Adapter. This may help a lot, since you can fetch all your data at once, then write it all at once.

Additionally, you can extend the transaction timeout for Oracle BPEL- it's a configuration parameter in transaction-manager.xml (there's also some tweaks to the EJB timeouts you need to do on 10.1.3.3.x & 10.1.3.4.x). The Oracle BPEL docs tell you how to change this variable.